# Strange bug when requesting DuckDuckGo using Python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use the Python requests library to fetch DuckDuckGo search results:

```
import requests
url = "https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=" + query + "&kl=us-en
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

This code works perfectly for almost any query. However, whenever my query contains double quotes " and a special character like the wildcard operator *, DuckDuckGo tells me that there are no search results even though, when I visit the corresponding page using my browser I can see there are results.

For example:

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=example&kl=us-en
https://duckduckgo.com/?q="example"&kl=us-en
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=*example&kl=us-en
```

all do work, but

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q="*example"&kl=us-en
```

always gets the response (shortened for clarity)

```
<title>"*example" at DuckDuckGo</title>
<link href="//duckduckgo.com/opensearch_html_v2.xml" rel="search" title="DuckDuckGo (HTML)" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"/>

</div>
<!-- Web results are present -->
<div>
<div class="serp__results">
<div class="results" id="links">
<div class="result results_links results_links_deep web-result result--no-result">
<div class="links_main links_deep result__body"> <!-- This is the visible part -->
<h2 class="result__title">
</h2>
<div class="no-results">No  results.</div>
```

This also happens when I'm rendering the regular DuckDuckGo website using a headless browser.

Moreover, the problem persists when I url-encode the query, e.g. use

```
https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%22%2Aexample%22&kl=us-en
```

Any request using Python yields "No results" but when I visit the link in my browser I can see many results.

I also experimented with different URL headers but couldn't make it work.

**Any ideas what else I could try would be much appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

Specify `User-Agent` HTTP header when making request to DDG server:

```py
import requests

url = "https://duckduckgo.com/html/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}
params = {
    "q": '"*example"',
    "kl": "us-en",
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
print(r.text)
```

Prints:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<!--[if IE 6]><html class="ie6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="lt-ie8 lt-ie9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="lt-ie9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=1" />
  <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <title>&quot;*example&quot; at DuckDuckGo</title>

...
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I'm using your code, I'm still getting "No Results" even though plenty of results show up when I visit the site manually. The header etc. looks exactly like what you posted but below that I always get <div class="no-results">No  results.</div> for these kind of queries whill other queries work fine.